# How can I handle an IDictionary with only the Keys strongly typed?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, types, polymorphism

I have a class with a static method which can operate on collections of objects of a couple of different types and act appropriately on them:

```
static void DoSomething(ICollection<TypeA> things)
{
    // Do something with TypeA elements
}

static void DoSomething(ICollection<TypeB> things)
{
    // Do something with TypeB elements
}
```

Elsewhere in my code there are a lot of dictionaries which use either `TypeA` or `TypeB` for their keys, and a variety of types for their values. I end up with a number of calls to `DoSomething(dictionary.Keys)`, which I think would be better served by methods which accept `dictionary` and pass on the `.Keys` collection to the appropriate overload.

It seems I can do this if I strongly type the dictionary:

```
static void DoSomething(IDictionary<TypeA,object> dictionary)
{
    DoSomething(dictionary.Keys);
}
```

but then I need an overload for every `IDictionary<TypeA,TValues>` which it might encounter, even though the method doesn't need to know what `TValues` is to work.

I alternatively seem to be able to accept a generic `IDictionary`, but then have to recast `Keys` to an appropriate type:

```
static void DoSomething(IDictionary dictionary)
{
    DoSomething((ICollection<TypeA>) dictionary.Keys);
}
```

This doesn't seem wise since calls using dictionaries with unsupported key types won't upset the compiler and I would presumably have to rely on Reflection to choose the correct overload.

Am I missing a better option?

Comment: does typeA and typeB share an interface or base class ? You could use generics

Comment: Would you mind using `dynamic`? `static void DoSomething(IDictionary<TypeA,dynamic> dictionary)`

Comment: I just tried this and the interpreter didn't seem to recognise a call to a method declared like this. Said "cannot convert from `IDictionary<TypeA,object>` to `ICollection<TypeA>`" - i.e. trying to pass it to a different overload. I'm not familiar with `dynamic` - does the declaration or call need to satisfy other conditions?

Comment: Info about `dynamic` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). You lose compile time type checking but it allows multiple types to be assigned to something expecting `dynamic`. E.g., run this code for an example: `            var dynamicValues = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>() { { "string", "hello" }, { "int", 3 }, { "double", 3.14159 } }; foreach (var kvp in dynamicValues)  {  Console.WriteLine("key=" + kvp.Key + " value=" + kvp.Value + " valueType=" + kvp.Value.GetType());  }`. It seems to be generally frowned upon but it makes certain things much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a generic method that accepts a type parameter for the type of the dictionary values:

```
static void DoSomething<TVALUE>(IDictionary<TypeA, TVALUE> dictionary)
{
    DoSomething(dictionary.Keys);
}
```

Comment: If TypeA and TypeB don't share same interace, isn't he going to need casting anyway? He would only access object interface if not

Comment: whe OP says "but then I need an overload for every IDictionary<TypeA,TValues> which it might encounter, even though the method doesn't need to know what TValues is to work." I think he wants to do all in one method

Comment: @Gonzalo.- He needs a separate method for both TypeA and TypeB (as there are separate `DoSomething(ICollection<TypeA>)` and `DoSomething(ICollection<TypeB>` methods. As I understand the question, the OP does not want to create separate methods for `TVALUE` but is fine with a separate method for `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

Comment: Yes, the I only distinguished between `TypeA` and `TypeB` because if *forced* to use one method with a generic `IDictionary` and deal with its type inside the method, this would add to the complexity inside the method. Making the method generic achieves exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do (if you have control over `TypeA` and `TypeB`) is to make both types implement an interface like this:

```
interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

...and change the dictionary to be a `Dictionary<IDoSomething, T>`.

Then you can simply iterate through the dictionary keys and call `DoSomething()` on each one.

Other solutions tend to violate the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). For example, if you do [as Markus suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42839638/3063273) then somewhere you'll wind up with a switch/series of if-statements like this:

```
if (key is TypeA)
    DoSomething<TypeA>(key);
else if (key is TypeB)
    DoSomething<TypeB>(key);
else
    throw new Exception();
```

This is a code smell and indicates violation of this principle. For example, what happens when you need to put a key of type `TypeC` into the dictionary? You have to remember to change the place where this code is (thus this code is not closed for modification). And if you forget then it's a runtime error instead of a compilation error. And the problem only gets worse as your code expands, because these switch/if-statements start popping up all over the place.

If you're unable to make `TypeA` and `TypeB` implement the same interface then perhaps there's another way to refactor toward [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). If you have any questions about something else in the context of this problem, I'm sure the SO community will be happy to answer a separate question.

Comment: The method in Markus's answer is still strongly-typed for keys of type `TypeA`, so it doesn't lead to runtime type logic. It merely requires separate declarations of this form for all types of dictionary key I want to treat in this way. Since `DoSomething` already has independent declarations for `ICollection<TypeA>` and `ICollection<TypeB>`, this is acceptable and to be expected from the way things have been structured so far. It is true that it would be more extensible to modify the types belonging to elements of supported collections, but this isn't specific to extending to dictionary keys.